# Drupal Context - contexts

Tags: drupal

Is it possible to achieve the following using the Drupal Context module:

- Show a block if the current logged in user is
  a member of the organic Group
- Show another block if the current
  logged in user is the admin of that
  organic group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a new context and give it conditions for the user role setting, selecting only the member role. Then you would create a new context and create the same condition, but you would also select the additional admin role. Both would have different reactions and the module then would evaluate each condition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is possible. 
Last time I used context and spaces, It did not have either-this-block-elsif-that-block logic. But you need to:

- set a block in the context "current-user-is-member-but-not-admin"
- set the other block in hte context "current-user-is-member-and-admin"

Comment: thanks for the answer, but im not sure I understand. Where to I place that logic as a context reaction ?